# Fix for "Invalid function:" error when external function become a macro

Tags: elisp-macros, byte-compilation

For:

```
(defun my-w3m-view-url ()
  (interactive)
  (browse-url (w3m-anchor)))
(eval-after-load 'w3m
  (define-key w3m-minor-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'my-w3m-view-url))
```

when byte-compiled I get error on key binding `RET` usage:

```
my-w3m-view-url: Invalid function: w3m-anchor
```

This because `w3m-anchor` isn't a function but become macro. I try to add:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'w3m-util nil :no-error))
```

before lines that uses `w3m-anchor`. But this doesn't help me.

I load `.emacs-my.elc` file made by:

```
emacs -Q --batch --eval='(byte-compile-file "~/.emacs.d/.emacs-my")'
```

**UPDATE** As suggest @Iqbal Ansari I further debug issue. For some reason byte compiled file have function call instead of expanded macro:

```
$ strings .emacs-my.elc | grep w3m-anchor
840:(defalias 'my-w3m-view-url #[nil "\300\301 !\207" [browse-url w3m-anchor] 2 nil nil])
```

Full `.emacs-my` file source code is available at https://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/dot-emacs/ci/default/tree/.emacs-my Corresponding installation steps are available at https://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/dot-emacs/ci/default/tree/Makefile

Comment: Did you try recompiling after adding missing `require`?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari Of course I recompile again )) Added further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm..., my error come from many parts after adaptation of install architecture.

I introduce byte-compilation for speed reason, that effect macro expansion.

Note that I used `-Q` option (to make compilation faster), which prevents built normal `load-path` value.

My `(require 'w3m-util nil :no-error)` style allow byte-compilation ever some packages doesn't preset at compile time. Changing code to `(require 'w3m-util)` has shown me where I am wrong.

So as solution I strip `-Q` from Emacs invocation during byte-compilation.

Comment: An alternative would be using `-L` with the path to the library needed.

Comment: If you feel your answer is correct, *and if you are not looking for other answers*, consider accepting your answer. that removes it from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: It's been more than 2 days by now...